# How can I extract all repeating items in a tuple of lists in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a tuple containing lists:

```
tuple = (["i",3,"h","n"],[2,3,"h",4],[3,"h","x"])
```

How can I extract all values that appear in every contained list?
E.g. In this case, I will get:

```
value = [3,"h"]
```

Comment: Do you want to have the items that are repeating or that are in all lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do to get the items that are repeating (at least once):

```
tuple = [["i",3,"h","n"],[2,3,"h",4],[3,"h","x"]]
temp_list = [item for sublist in tuple for item in sublist] #makes one long list out of a list of lists
value = list(set([i for i in temp_list if temp_list.count(i)==len(tuple)])) 
#counts the number of times each element of 'temp_list' is occuring
print(value)
```

prints out:

```
[3, 'h']
```

Comment: [i for i in temp_list if temp_list.count(i)>1] needs to be replaced with [i for i in temp_list if temp_list.count(i)==len(tuple)]

Comment: @ZedMaster yes I replaced it now. The "topic line" of your post was misleading me as it only said "repeating"

Comment: If you count values you don't need `set`. You can use `Counter()` for that.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert all the sublists to sets, and then take the intersection between all of them.

```
>>> data = [["i",3,"h","n"],[2,3,"h",4],[3,"h","x"]]
>>> common = set(data[0])
>>> for item in data:
        common = common.intersection(item)
>>> common
{3, 'h'}
```

Or even more compact:

```
>>> data = [["i",3,"h","n"],[2,3,"h",4],[3,"h","x"]]
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(set.intersection, map(set, data))
{3, 'h'}
```